# How to make custom memoizeOne function return correct type

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a function to memoize an object:

```
import memoizeOne from 'memoize-one';

type ArrayWithOneObj = [Record<string, unknown>];
const compareObject = ([obj1]: ArrayWithOneObj, [obj2]: ArrayWithOneObj) =>
  obj1 === obj2 ||
  (Object.keys(obj1).length === Object.keys(obj2).length &&
    Object.keys(obj1).every(key => obj2.hasOwnProperty(key) && obj1[key] === obj2[key]));

const identity = (x: Record<string, unknown>) => x;
const memoizeObj = memoizeOne(identity, compareObject);

// USING IT:

type FruityObj = {
  name: string;
};

const apple1: FruityObj = { name: 'apple' };
const apple2: FruityObj = { name: 'apple' };

// This works but the type of the memoized variables should be FruityObj instead
// of Record<string, unknown>
const memoizedApple1 = memoizeObj(apple1);
const memoizedApple2 = memoizeObj(apple2);
console.log(memoizedApple1 === memoizedApple2);
```

How can I modify so that `memoizeObj` returns the type that was passed in? I'm not sure how to pass a [Generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) to `memoizeObj`? Thanks

Here is a runnable example: https://codesandbox.io/s/memoizeobj-bq3r8?file=/src/index.ts

Declaration of `memoizeOne`:

```
export declare type EqualityFn = (newArgs: any[], lastArgs: any[]) => boolean;
export default function memoizeOne<ResultFn extends (this: any, ...newArgs: any[]) => ReturnType<ResultFn>>(resultFn: ResultFn, isEqual?: EqualityFn): ResultFn;
```

Comment: Can you share the declaration of `memoizeOne`, please?

Comment: @Bergi sure added, thanks

Comment: I guess you would need to make `identity` generic (and probably `memoizeObj` as well to allow inference)

Answer (score 0):

This was a lot simpler than I thought, I was trying to add the Generic type to the const assignment of `memoizeObj` but all I needed was:

```
function identity<T>(x: T) {
  return x;
}
```